# Sparse Blas in Fortran 95

Tags: fortran, sparse-matrix, fortran90, blas, finite-element-analysis

I want to use the Sparse Blas in Fortran95 just for the creation of the matrices and I am using the point entry construction. After creation of the matrix using the command

call duscr_begin(n,n,a,istat)

here a is the handle to the matrix n by n. After inserting value in it, how can I see the final matrix using its handles a ? As I want to use the matrix for some other operation, so I want to see the matrix in three vectors (sparse) form (row_index, Col_index, Value).

detail about this Sparse Blas is given in Chapter 3 and can be seen here

http://www.netlib.org/blas/blast-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually what i have asked is before 16 days and it is not just writing of a variable to thee screen. I was using some library known as Sparse Blas for creation of the Sparse matrices. Later on by digging in to the library i found the solution to my problem that using the handles how can we get the three vectors row, col and Val. The commands are something like

```
call accessdata_dsp(mat,a_handle,ierr)
call get_infoa(mat%INFOA,'n',nnz,ierr)
allocate(K0_row(nnz),K0_col(nnz),K0_A(nnz))
K0_row=mat%IA1; K0_col=mat%IA2; K0_A=mat%A
```

so here nnz are the non zeros entries in the sparse matrix while K0_row, K0_col and K0_A are our required three vectors, which can be used in further calculation.